# I need to show all associated products of config if all of them are out of stock

Tags: magento2

For e.g. If i have a config product with 1 associated product & that associated product is out of stock, then by default magento2 will display out of stock message & this associated option will not be shown. I wasnt to show this associated option even when that single product is out of stock.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using backorders? https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html or also under "advanced inventory" on product, select turn off `Manage stock`?  or in `Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory` set `Display Out of Stock Products` to `Yes`

Comment: I need to only display price & options